# Remove chinese characters in foldername

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, rename, batch-rename

I am running windows server 2003 and I need to find a way to mass rename folders that contains chinese characters. Basically I want to remove chinese characters but if I remove it then the folder name won't have a name so I need to replace it with some random 5 digit letter/numbers.

Any solutions?

Comment: Windows may already have done so for you http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000209.htm

Comment: @Amazed: Which ancient version of Windows are you talking about? :)

Comment: @Karan Every one that supports NTFS.

Comment: @Amazed: So you're talking about the 8.3 short names? I doubt that sort of shortening is acceptable in this case, but it's up to the OP of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Ken Rename](http://myprogramspace.blogspot.in/2008/07/krename-multi-file-rename-tool-v0.html).

I first changed the settings to replace all illegal characters with underscores:

[image: 1]

Next I selected the option to change the [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) of the filenames from [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) to [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). This replaced the Chinese characters with question marks, which, being wildcards and thus illegal filename characters in Windows, were in turn replaced by underscores:

[image: 2]

In case this does not suffice and you really need it, there might be a way to replace the characters with random digits as well, but I didn't check.

Comment: I just noticed that there are a few folders that didn't get rename. Examples: `code`[Mokusa] R.MikaおっぱいCG集 [526015] 
`code`[Visual Biscuits]S.D. -_魔のウルラさんにひたすら_り取られちゃう系CG集- [525769]

Comment: No sure why this is happening TBH. Are those all valid Chinese characters?

Comment: it's actually japanese characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {
    $n = $_.BaseName -replace '[\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}]'
    while ($n -match '^\s*$' -or (Test-Path (Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent $_.FullName) $n)) {
      $n = -join(0..5|%{[char[]](65..90+97..122+48..57)|Get-Random})
    }
    Rename-Item $_.FullName ($n + $_.Extension)
  }
```

This removes all CJK Ideographs from the file name (you might need to extend the character class a bit with other blocks if necessary) and if it is empty afterwards or clashes with an existing name a random alphanumeric name will be generated.